# Can't get the html code for the like button on my webpage

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

When I enter my webpage into the "get Like button Url to like" on [Facebook's Like Button Generator](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), it tells me that the href entered is not a valid url, when in fact it is.

How can I get the url for my webpage without this application?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the like button generator to get the code for a site you know, like `www.google.com`
2. Look through the code and replace `www.google.com` with `yoursite.com`

Once you have you like button set up, you should set up [Open Graph meta information](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/), and you can test that everything is set up properly using the [Facebook Debug Console](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)